# Why google sheet script changes rows I don't want it to change?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I want to change values of row in Array, when it has the same resident and the same medication as in previous row.

Initially it looks if it is repeated task - if so, sets default value "More":

```
//check if something from one time per day
    if (startTime[resMedVals[resMedRow][3]]){
      medPlan[lastRow].push(startTime[resMedVals[resMedRow][3]]+":00");                
    }else{
      medPlan[lastRow].push("More")
    }//end if time
```

Then it goes back and deals with "More" values. If it is first time repeating task, then sets initial start time value. If repeating, then copies as many rows as needed.

```
//if more times per day medicine, then replicate tasks
    if(medPlan[lastRow][9]== "More"){
      var timesToReplicate = medPlan[lastRow][5].charAt(0)

      for(var i=0; i < timesToReplicate; i++){
        if (i==0){
          //first time
          medPlan[lastRow][9] = workDay["start"]
          medPlan[lastRow][9] += ":00"

        }else{

          //add entire last entire row
          medPlan.push(medPlan[medPlan.length-1]);

        }//end if else first time
```

Till this part everything works properly.

Then I want to set different value for the repeated (and not first) values.

```
    //adjust More values to appropriate starting times
  for (var med=1; med < medPlan.length; med++){
    if(medPlan[med][2] == medPlan[med-1][2] && medPlan[med][1] == medPlan[med-1][1]){
      Logger.log(med)
      var interval =  Math.floor(workingHours / medPlan[med][5].charAt(0));

      medPlan[med][9] = interval
    }//end if the same medication and the same resident

  }//end for medPlan
```

But it keeps changing also the first row of the repeating tasks, even though Logs show that it determines right row.

[image: Log output]
Current result:
[image: Current result]

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: can you post the code that actually sets the values in the sheet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was problem of referencing. Had to add .slice(0) to solve the problem.

```
medPlan.push(medPlan[medPlan.length-1].slice(0));
```